# Ball game: chance of winning given probability p of making a shot and n starting balls

Tags: probability

I was thinking the other night and I came up with this problem:

You are playing a game involving balls and making shots. Suppose you have probability $p$ of making a shot. If you make a shot, you lose the ball. If you miss, however, you are given two balls back, i.e. you now have one more ball than before you took the shot. Winning is defined as running out of balls with which to make a shot. You may shoot an infinite number of times or until you run out of balls.

Given $n$ starting balls, what is the probability of winning and, if you do finish, the expected number of shots made.

I've been thinking about a solution and haven't made any headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice problem! It might help to find a recurrence relation first. That is, let $P(n,m)$ be the probability that you have $n$ balls after $m$ shots, so that $P(1,0)=1,P(0,1)=p$ and $P(2,1)=1-p$. Then clearly,
$$P(n,m)=(1-p)P(n-1,m-1)+pP(n+1,m-1).$$
This isn't pretty, but then you could try generating functions, if you've seen those, to find an explicit expression for $P(n,m)$.

Comment: I actually did find this recurrence relationship (slightly different in form), but was unsure of how to solve it. (I totally forgot to add that to my question.) I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: I just realised that this is just the standard Gambler's ruin problem. There's a plethora of material out there about this!

Comment: So winning is guaranteed (I had a hunch about this), no? Then it becomes a question of how many balls are used.

Comment: Not from what I remember. I think that it is guaranteed provided the expected return is not positive.